# iOS slow SQL query within the viewDidLoad method

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I've got a chat app that is based on a navigation controller.

Within the view that displays the conversation i load all the previous history from SQLite within the `viewDidLoad` method.

When a conversation grows it takes a few seconds to open up the view and therefore feels "laggy".

Below is my code that i use to load the history from the database.

Any ideas what could be improved to make the UI feel more responsive?

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM chatHistory WHERE channelID = '%@' ORDER BY time ASC", box.activeChannel];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2([box db], [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSString *channelID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field1];

        char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        NSString *sender = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field2];

        char *field3 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field3];

        char *field4 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        NSString *recipient = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field4];

        char *field5 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
        NSString *time = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field5];

        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", message];
        NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", channelID];
        NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", sender];
        NSString *str3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", time];


        NSString *trimmedStr2 = [str2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                 [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSString *trimmedAgentName = [box.agentName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                      [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSString *trimmedTime = [str3 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                 [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
        NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:trimmedTime];


        if ([trimmedStr2 isEqualToString:trimmedAgentName]) {
            [self.messages addObject:[[JSMessage alloc] initWithText:str sender:trimmedAgentName date:myDate]];
            [self finishSend];
            [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
        } else {
            [self.messages addObject:[[JSMessage alloc] initWithText:str sender:kSubtitleVisitor date:myDate]];
            [self finishSend];
            [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I've also tried to put the code inside a `dispatch_queue`, that made the switch to the view go a lot faster but the messages are still lagging behind when being added.

Comment: try to not load everything at once, just read a few number of rows from your db and if the user want to see more read another couple of rows and so on

Answer (score 0):

There are some places you can optimise in your code:

- No need to create `str` `str1` `str2` `str3`, just use the `message` `channelID` `sender` `time`.
- `NSDateFormatter` creation is expansive, you should create a instance outside the while loop.
- `viewDidLoad` is called in UI thread, the query will take a long time to execute and block UI, you might want to execute SQL query in background. See Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) for more.